# CPU and GPU Tensorflow Installation

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I'm very new with TensorFlow.

I want to run my code on my CUDA gpu. So I've installed TensorFlow -gpu, after I've installed normal TensorFlow.

How can I tell Python that it takes gpu based TensorFlow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have tensorflow-gpu installed there really isn't any reason to also have tensorflow. Without the presence of a gpu it will just run on cpu anyway.

To be specific in which GPU you use:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"
```

in place of `"0"` you can either list GPUs (if you have multiple), or `""` if you want it to run on cpu.

alternatively, specify in the session:

```
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(device_count={'GPU': 0}))
```

Furthermore you can check which version your computer prioritizes by opening python console and typing:

```
>>> import tensorflow
>>> tensorflow
<module 'tensorflow' from 
'/home/.../python3.6/site- packages/tensorflow/__init__.py'>
                                       ^
                                       |
                                      here
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

I found that my GPU has only CUDA 3.0, so it won't work with Tensorflow-gpu.

Why doesn't the variable "sess" appear in the Variable explorer (I use Spyder)? I want to read its attributes.

I've downloaded/installed tensorflow-gpu via "pip install tensorflow-gpu", but there is only tensorflow_gpu-1.12.0.dist-info in my site-packages. Hase something gone wrong?

Comment: I am not sure about the intricacies of Spyder, but as far as I am aware it should appear if you have instantiated it properly. In my answer sess is an instance of [tf.Session](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/client/session.py). More accessible help on that [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session). This is usually used in the form of a context manager (`with tf.Session as sess:`).  To use it as a variable see [tf.Interactive_Session](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/InteractiveSession)

Comment: And yes, if you only have the dist info module in your environment, that does sound wrong. There should also be tensorflow-gpu module also. (I recommend using [miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) and creating an environment using `conda create --name my_env tensorflow-gpu`). See [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) for more.